# Remote host closed connection during handshake when using onesignal push notification service

Tags: java, onesignal

I have an android application and I am using onesignal for push notification ..
I send notifications from my server using onesignal API for that (can be found here https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference under the title "Example Code - Create notification" . I am coping the java code since I am using spring boot in the backend...until yesterday,every thing was fine but today when trying to send a notification I am getting the following Exception in an annoying way :

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:992)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1316)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1291)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
```

my IDE says the problem is exactly in this line:

```
OutputStream outputStream = con.getOutputStream();
```

what is the cause and how to solve it?? is it a reliability problem with Onesignal?

Comment: Sounds like bad port. Like attempt to establish ssl connection on non ssl port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well , I have discovered the problem and it seems to be a strange one ... at the same time I was testing there was a running VPN client(hotspot shield) im my computer ... I just stopped it and the problem never come again (until now at least :) ).